# Why top-bottom and bottom-up work differently in my code of Lua?

Tags: lua, dynamic-programming

I make a code of dynamic program. It is about searching the smallest number of calculations in three ways : divided by 3, divided by 2, or subtracted by 1 to a given number to make it 1.

First, I made a function 'one' with top-bottom way. But when I put 1,000,000 in there, it results stack overflow.

Second, I made a function 'two' with bottom-up way. It works with the input 1,000,000 well.

```lua
local num = io.read("*n")

local memo = {
    [0] = 0,
    [1] = 0
}

function one(n)
    if memo[n] == nil then
        if n % 3 == 0 then
            memo[n] = 1 + math.min(one(n-1), one(n//3))
        elseif n % 2 == 0 then
            memo[n] = 1 + math.min(one(n-1), one(n//2))
        else
            memo[n] = 1 + one(n-1)
        end
    end
    return memo[n]
end

local last = 1

function two(n)
    if memo[n] == nil then
        for i = last + 1, n do
            if i % 3 == 0 then
                memo[i] = 1 + math.min(two(i-1), two(i//3))
            elseif i % 2 == 0 then
                memo[i] = 1 + math.min(two(i-1), two(i//2))
            else
                memo[i] = 1 + two(i-1)
            end
        end
        last = n
    end
    return memo[n]
end



print(two(num))
```

I don't know why this happened. Isn't it work quiet similarly?

Comment: You have an extra `/` in your math for the value / 2 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a stack overflow from top-bottom because no lower numbers are defined.

Lets go through the both functions if we provide an input of 5, I added print lines to the code to help illustrate how code is running.

---

I will start with function two.

```
Undefined: 5 -- This is the first call.
Undefined: 2  -- first value once in the for loop.
%2: 2         -- Enter mod 2 block.
Defined: 1    -- Second call. (now 2 calls deep)
Defined: 1    -- Third call. (still 2 calls deep)
Undefined: 3  -- Next  value in First calls for loop. (back to 1 deep)
%3: 3         -- Enter mod 3 block.
Defined: 2    -- Forth call. (now  2 calls deep)
Defined: 1    -- Fifth call. (still 2 calls deep)
Undefined: 4  -- Next  value in First calls for loop. (back to 1 deep)
%2: 4         -- Enter mod 4 block.
Defined: 3    -- Sixth call. (now 2 calls deep)
Defined: 2    -- Seventh call. (still 2 calls deep)
Undefined: 5  -- Next  value in First calls for loop. (back to 1 deep)
else: 5       -- Enter else block.
Defined: 4    -- Eighth call. (still 2 calls deep)
3             -- return from initial call.
```

As you can see every iteration of the loop as the previous values already defined so they return immediately and it do not really perform recursion more than 2 calls deep.

---

Here is the output for function one:

```
Undefined: 5 -- This is the first call.
else: 5      -- Enter the else block.
Undefined: 4 -- Second call. (now 2 calls deep)
%2: 4        -- Enter mod 2 block.
Undefined: 3 -- Third call. (now 3 calls deep)
%3: 3        -- Enter mod 3 block.
Undefined: 2 -- Forth call. (now 4 calls deep)
%2: 2        -- Enter mod 2 block.
Defined: 1   -- Fifth call. (now 5 calls deep)
Defined: 1   -- Sixth call. (still 5 calls deep)
Defined: 1   -- Seventh call. (Second call from value 3)
Defined: 2   -- Eighth call. (Second call from value 4)
3            -- return from initial call.
```

Here each call has to go deeper and deeper as no lower values are defined.
This results in the stack overflow.

function two is not really recursive like function one, you could just do `memo[i-1]` and `memo[i/2]` as they are garenteed to be to have already been processed.